# Send single hidden field with form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms, input

Currently I'm working with `ASP.Net` and a *nested* form. My problem is,
that `ASP.Net` only allows one form per page, but I need a kind of sub-form
to redirect to another page.

My idea was to create a `submit` using JavaScript, but I don't get how to set the
content of the `post`, which will be send.

For example I've tried to use the following code:

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="ABCDE" />
    <input title="Send Form" onclick="this.form.method = 'post'; this.form.action = 'https://externpage/url'; this.form.submit();" type="submit" />
</div>
```

My problem is, that the content of the request should only be the `hidden fields` containing `ABCDE` and not all fields on the page. How can i achieve this using `JavaScript` and `HTML`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think in `ASP.NET WEbForms` you can get `tag` by Id in `codebehind`

Comment: I redirect to another extern page. They need the hidden value in the content of the request. But I don't know how they are working later with this.

Comment: Try `PreviousPage.FindControl("yourId")`

Comment: @UthmanRahimi Nope, he needs `runat=server` for finding the control.

Comment: @UthmanRahimi I think we are talking about two different things. I don't need to access any control on the server side.

Comment: Are these piece of codes actually inside a form tag?

Comment: @choz yes they are. And I can not prevent from this. Because this code is in a DNN-Module, which automatically wraps every thing in a `form`.

Comment: I am suggesting to give `name` attribute to the hidden field. And use breakpoints to check the post parameters on `asp.net` side.

Comment: @choz thank you for your answer. But how can I set the breakpoint, when clicking the `button` leaves my website? Because the action points to `https://externpage/url` which has written some one else.

Comment: Have you tried to set the other fields to disabled with the `disabled` html attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to do the encoding.

```
sendForm=(e)=>{
    let data = new FormData();
    let hidden = document.querySelector('button').parentNode.firstChild.value;
    data.append('hidden',hidden);
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=()=>(xhr.readyState == 4) ? console.log(xhr.response) : null;
    xhr.open('POST','http://yoururl.com');
    xhr.send(data);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',sendForm);
});
```